# Help me to create a Skype call link with markdown

Tags: markdown

From [this page](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/) I learn how to extract my personal skype user name link: `skype:username?call` . When inserting it into a paragraph using markdown, `[Skype](skype:username?call)`, the link (when posting the note via [nvALT](http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/) to [peg.gd](http://peg.gd)) shows up but does not work. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use this to call on Skype.

```
callto:<username>?call
```

HTML markup:

```
<a href="callto:<username>?call">Call</a>
```

And this works, I have tested on peg.gd.

Eventually this also works:

```
skype:<username>?call
```

HTML markup:

```
<a href="skype:<username>?call">Call</a>
```

This might be a problem with protocol on your system (if the `skype:` thing does not work).

**And about the markdown, it works, I used:**

```
[Skype](skype:<username>?call)
```

Comment: Thank you. It does indeed work on peg.gd as you say. I realise that there is something that goes wrong when I share it to peg.gd via nvALT. That is where the problem occurs.

Comment: I had to remove ?call so this worked for me: <a href="callto:<username>">Call</a>

Comment: Actually, just that also works in newer versions of Skype. Sometimes some over VoIP apps may use this protocol.